# simple python list comprehension question

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i am trying to select the elements of a list without the very first element. the following code works but it kinda look ugly to me

```
[s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if i>0]
```

is there a better way to write it? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the slicing notation:

```
s[1:]
```

Alternatively, you can avoid copying the list thus:

```
itertools.islice(s, 1, None)
```

The result isn't a list — it doesn't support random access, for instance — but you can pass it to anything that accepts an iterator.

Comment: For completeness' sake, `islice` is a bit problematic when you want to slice out from the middle of a larger list. It creates a iterator but then walks to the start of the slice by calling `next`, possibly many times. Slicing is very fast because Python just has to copy the list structure and no data.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `s[1:]` be correct?